# Is the lack of articles in these sentences weird to you?

Tags: articles

1,The long contest between **predator and prey** has produced mimicry of astouding accuracy.
2,Their views of the relations between **man and woman** are limited.
3,The relation between **teacher and student** is not what it used to be.
4,The relations between **parent and child** are excellent.
5,Apparently relations between **husband and wife** had not improved.
6,[**Mother and son** lost contact when Nicholas was in his early twenties.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-lose-contact)
7,**Doctor, nurse and patient** have become the best friends.
8,He was **printer, publisher and editor** before 1949.

Maybe they are pairs so articles could be omitted?

Comment: It is not in the least unusual, far less [weird](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/weird). This usage is perfectly standard in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*With* articles **would** be weird.  Example 2 means ...*men* and *women*...  You *could* put 'the' before husband in example 5 but it is superfluous. You only need to be pedantic if there is doubt about the meaning.  Here we know what's on the table so no need.